# Python error checking

Tags: python, error-checking

I have code snippet below I would like to add error checking Like

```
"If  p > 10000 dont append list with record,
```

How would I do this?

```
for line in idata.split("\r\n"):
        if line == '':
            continue
        s, p, v, time = line.split(',')
        try:
            if isRecordValid(s,p,v,time): 
                s = s[1:-1]
                p = (float(p)) 
                v = int(v)
                time = time[1:-1]
                scol.append((s, p, v, time))   #moved this                  
        except Exception as e: pass #  print "log and error here, using " , stock
```

Comment: `except Exception as e: pass` (or `...: log error, then ignore it`) - because walking on like nothing happened when you got run over by a car is totally a good idea. Either truly handle an exception or let it propagate (yes, up to crashing the whole app if you can't handle it at all).

Comment: +1 @delnan.  Always a valid point.

Comment: Error code is allowed to fail elsewhere just not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding something in the `isRecordValid` method?  Without knowing what the rest of it looks like, you could simple add this to start:

```
def isRecordValid(s, p, v, time):
    if p > 10000:
        return False
    ... 
    # rest of existing method
```